# How do I fix ':' expected.ts(1005) in a for-of loop in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I am doing is reading a JSON file located in the `public` directory of my React project in the `CardContainer` component, as can be seen below:

```
import { useAsync } from "react-async";

type ProjectData = {
    title: string,
    desc: string,
    website: string,
    repo: string,
    tags: Array<string>
}

type ProjectContainerData = {
    projects: Array<ProjectData>
}

async function getData() {
  let output: ProjectContainerData | undefined = undefined;
  await fetch("/myProjects.json")
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      output = JSON.parse(data);
    });
  return output;
}

function CardContainer() {
  const { data, error, isPending } = useAsync(getData);
    for (let project of data?["projects"]) {
      // error is here
    }
  return <></>;
}

export default CardContainer;
```

When I am editing my code, I see the `':' expected.ts(1005)` error. When I try to compile it with `npm start`, I see the same thing:

```
ERROR in src/components/CardContainer.tsx:27:42
TS1005: ':' expected.
    25 | function CardContainer() {
    26 |   const { data, error, isPending } = useAsync(getData);
  > 27 |     for (let project of data?["projects"]) {
       |                                          ^
    28 |
    29 |     }
    30 |   return <></>;
```

My TypeScript version is `4.9.5`. Is there any way to easily avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

`?[...]` operator does not exist, the right syntax for it is `?.[...]`

Hence `?.['projects']`, or `?.projects`

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax

Comment: I'm getting a `property 'projects' does not exist on type 'never'`

Comment: @vs07 then it's a different new question/problem then. The question you asked originally is about incorrect syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Update: The error goes away when I change this:

```
const { data, error, isPending } = useAsync(getData);
```

to this:

```
const { data, error, isPending } = useAsync<ProjectContainerData | any>(getData);
```

and when I change this:

```
for (let project of data?["projects"]) {
```

to this:

```
for (let project of data.projects) {
```

Comment: `ProjectContainerData | any` <- do you really want this type? How is it different to `any`?

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: how do i tell TS to assign the `any` type to the other two vars, and the `ProjectContainerData` to just the `data` variable?

Comment: @vs07 `T | any` is exactly the same as `any`, just as @zerkms points out. Moreover, explicit type arguments won't affect syntax errors that are being raised in value positions.

Comment: The question mark is being parsed as the start of a ternary operator expression. Use `for (const project of data?.projects ?? [])` or `for (const project of data?.["projects"] ?? [])`